# Unexpected behaviour of UDEV + USB device detection

Tags: usb, embedded-linux, yocto, udev

I am working with an embedded platform running Linux (Yocto). I have created a set of UDEV rules that detect the plug/unplug of an external USB sound card. The rules are firing some scripts used for audio capturing, etc.

`ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",  DRIVERS=="snd-usb-audio",  RUN+="/usr/bin/audio.sh start"`

`ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="xxxxxx", RUN+="/usr/bin/audio.sh stop"`

The first time I connect and disconnect the device, everything works as expected: device is enumerated and recognised correctly and rules are fired starting and stopping the script. The erroneous behaviour begins when I reconnect the device; exactly one minute later I'm getting the message:

`udevd[128]: worker [559] /devices/platform/soc/2100000.bus/2184000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 is taking a long time`

In the meantime, the `"add"` rule has fired and the script has run. Two minutes after that the following messages appear:

`[981.155879] udevd[559]: timeout '/usr/bin/audio.sh start'`

`[984.571667] usb 1-1: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x81, wValue = 0x202, wIndex = 0x200, type = 4`

`[984.622923] usb 1-1: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x81, wValue = 0x202, wIndex = 0x200, type = 4`

`[984.676660] usb 1-1: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x81, wValue = 0x102, wIndex = 0x200, type = 1`

If I disconnect the device at this point, the "remove" UDEV rule is fired correctly and stops the process. If I do it earlier, then the "remove" rule does not fire at all, until this worker times out.

Now, I have checked my script and reduced it, to basically run only one command. In that case, the messages are different:

`[1924.275992] udevd[128]: worker [843] /devices/platform/soc/2100000.bus/2184000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 timeout; kill it`

`[1924.301369] udevd[128]: seq 2041 '/devices/platform/soc/2100000.bus/2184000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0' killed`

`[1924.313188] udevd[128]: worker [843] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)`

`[1924.326581] udevd[128]: worker [843] failed while handling '/devices/platform/soc/2100000.bus/2184000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0'`

I have tried reducing the timeout by changing the `event_timeout` property in udev.conf to 5 seconds; however, no change in the behaviour. I have also tried with different devices, however the results are exactly the same. At this point I don't have the slightest idea of where to even begin looking, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the device work upon reconnection if you remove your own udev rules?

Comment: @skandigraun Eventually I took a completely different approach. However, yes the device was still working.